# update key of specific dict in dict of dicts

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm creating a dictionary of dictionaries and then trying to update a specific key using for loop.
however, all keys are getting updated.

code is as follows:

```
transactions = Transaction.objects.all()

unique_sellers = ['A002638841D', 'A09876543456']
seller_summary={}
summary = {
        'total_loan_amount': 0,
        'gross_incentive': 0,
        }

for each in unique_sellers:
    seller_summary[each] = summary
    seller_summary[each]['total_loan_amount'] = transactions.filter(channel_seller__pin_no = each).aggregate(total_loan_amount=Sum('loan_amount'))['total_loan_amount']

print(seller_summary)
```

total_loan_amount for `A002638841D` is 1500

total_loan_amount for `A09876543456` is 2000

my expectations is output of `print(seller_summary)` should be `{'A002638841D': {'total_loan_amount': 1500, 'gross_incentive': 0,}, 'A09876543456': { 'total_loan_amount': 2000, 'gross_incentive': 0,}}`

However, I'm getting output as follows my expectations is output of  `{'A002638841D': {'total_loan_amount': 2000, 'gross_incentive': 0,}, 'A09876543456': { 'total_loan_amount': 2000, 'gross_incentive': 0,}}`

total_loan_amount is both the dict is getting updated as 2000 instead of 1500 and 2000 respectively

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the `summary` dict for each key, summary is a reference of the original summary variable, so you update twice the same dict.
Maybe you could try

```py
transactions = Transaction.objects.all()

unique_sellers = ['A002638841D', 'A09876543456']
seller_summary={}
def get_summary(): # create a new reference each time instead of using the same one
    return {
        'total_loan_amount': 0,
        'gross_incentive': 0,
    }

for each in unique_sellers:
    seller_summary[each] = get_summary()
    # EDIT: Or like said in comments, simply create the dict reference here :
    # seller_summary[each] = {  'total_loan_amount': 0, 'gross_incentive': 0,}
    seller_summary[each]['total_loan_amount'] = transactions.filter(channel_seller__pin_no = each).aggregate(total_loan_amount=Sum('loan_amount'))['total_loan_amount']

print(seller_summary)
```

Comment: This was my exact problem. Instead of `get_summary()` , i just created the dict for `seller_summary[each]` and it worked. Thanks again

Comment: One could also use `seller_summary[each] = dict(seller_summary)` or `seller_summary[each] = seller_summary.copy()`.